# Ads for this site on Stack Overflow show questions with bad grammar

Tags: discussion

I was browsing Stack Overflow when I saw the following ad for Information Security on the right side of my window:

[image: Do one need to be a good programmer to perform secure source code analysis?]

As you can see, this question title has bad grammar. It should read "*Does* one need to be a good programmer...". [The question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/106382/32998) has since been edited.

I'm guessing that this was an automated ad based on hot-network questions. But it seems to me like allowing ads like this to appear on Stack Overflow makes this site appear unprofessional. I could see someone thinking "they can't even form a properly worded question, how could they produce a quality answer"?

Is there something that could be done to make sure that questions with bad grammar don't get turned into ads like this? Maybe have human-verification before it turns into an ad?

Comment: Related, on meta.SE: [Encourage active users to edit Hot Questions, especially titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286248/164541)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the vast number of questions every hour across the Stack Exchange network, I can't imagine any better way to do this than allowing each community to edit posts on each site - which is what currently happens.

And you can be part of this - propose edits to fix grammar and spelling. Get things fixed quickly and early and the adverts will look better.

Comment: Sadly, I couldn't propose an edit to this question because of my lack of reputation on this site, but that's good advice generally.

Comment: Don't worry Thunderforge, it doesn't take long to gain the rep required for edits.

Comment: @Thunderforge: Anyone can propose an edit for a question, it is not even needed to have an account on any SE website. The reputation matters only for the edit to be applied immediately instead of being queued for review.

Comment: Lack of reputation blocks suggested edits only on Meta sites, @Thunderforge.